# how to get web-scraped data into tabular format by using csv files or text files (no using pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have data scraped from a website and i need to make it into into a csv file and then read that file and display it

please dont use pandas and convert it into a dataframe and then convert  that to a csv file

i want a way where the scraped data is directly written to a csv file and then also the data from the csv file needs to be read and displayed in python idle

the following is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url="https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l=India"
page_data=requests.get(start_url) #sending a http request to the site
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_data.content,"html.parser") #getting that requested data to store in an object

#lists in which the data is going to be appended
Title=[]
Company=[]
Summary=[]
Location=[]
Link_to_apply=[]
  

for job_tag in soup.find_all("div",class_="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result"):  

    title=job_tag.find("h2",class_="title")
    company=job_tag.find("span",class_="company")
    location=job_tag.find(class_="location accessible-contrast-color-location").text.strip()
    summary=job_tag.find("div",class_="summary")
    link=job_tag.find("a",href=True)
    base_url="https://www.indeed.com"
    final_link=base_url+link["href"]

   Title.append(title.text.replace('/n'," ").strip())   ###text removes all the unwanted text and gives only the data
   Company.append(company.text.replace('\n'," ").strip())## replace() its replces new lines with just 1 space bar
   Summary.append(summary.text.replace('\n'," ").strip())#strip() replaces all leading and trailing spaces
   Location.append(location.replace('\n'," "))
   Link_to_apply.append(final_link)
```

please note only python idle can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked two questions in one go. The following approach should answer both of them. The first part of it write the scrape data in a csv file and the last part of it reads the data from the newly created csv file. You better put the script in a folder and execute it so that you can get the csv file within the same folder.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.indeed.com"
start_url = "https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l=India"

page_data = requests.get(start_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_data.content,"html.parser")

with open("output.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['title','company','location','summary','final_link'])
    for job_tag in soup.find_all("div",class_="jobsearch-SerpJobCard"):  
        title = job_tag.find("h2",class_="title").get_text(strip=True)
        company = job_tag.find("span",class_="company").get_text(strip=True)
        location = job_tag.find(class_="location").get_text(strip=True)
        summary = job_tag.find("div",class_="summary").get_text(strip=True)
        link = job_tag.find("a",href=True)
        final_link = base_url + link["href"]
        writer.writerow([title,company,location,summary,final_link])

with open("output.csv","r",encoding="utf-8-sig") as r:
    reader = csv.DictReader(r)
    for item in reader:
        print(item['title'],item['company'])
```

Comment: it gives an error
the error is posted down
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sajim/Pictures/New folder/stack overflow try.py", line 21, in <module>
    writer.writerow([title,company,location,summary,final_link])
  File "C:\Users\sajim\Desktop\python official\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 122: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: That was because of encoding. I've modified the above script. Try now.

Comment: eventhough i didnt get en error is there a way for the data  now to be displayed in a tabular column or any table format..The  output is bit cluttered thats why.

Do you know  a way SIM

Comment: Ain't this [tabular format](https://imgur.com/fmDs8Mv)? This is what the script should produce unless you modify manually.

Comment: i know its tabular format in csv file 
what i meant was ,is there a way for the table to be displayed in idle without it geting truncated

Comment: aslo SIM happy new year ..have a great and wonderful year ahead